# Finding Endpoint of line in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, vector, geometry

I have a startpoint, magnitude(length) and direction and want to find endpoint to construct the line
here is the code to make question more clear

```
private Vector2 GetEndPoint(Vector2 startPoint, Vector2 direction, float magnitude) {
    Vector2 endPoint = //some stfuff with parameters
    return endPoint;
}
```

And this is the visualization of what I want

[image: And this is the visualization of what I want]

Hope I am clear enough, any suggestions is welcomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be simply:

```
Vector2 endPoint = startPoint + direction.normalized * magnitude;
```

Though you can omit the `.normalized` if you can guarantee your input direction is a unit vector already (ie. it is exactly 1 unit in length)

You can also do this with the `Ray` type, if you find that clearer:

```
Ray ray = new Ray(startPoint, direction);
Vector2 endPoint = ray.GetPoint(magnitude);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simple vector math.

```
return startPoint + direction.normalized * magnitude;
```

If the direction is already normalized (it has a magnitude of 1.0), you can of course omit the `.normalized`.

Comment: Oops, looks like we were typing almost identical answers at the same time. XD Well, at least OP has confirmation that this code makes sense to multiple devs now. :)

Comment: Thanks both of you so much, it's what I wanted